# Exclude date list from datetime list c#

Tags: c#, list, datetime

I have been trying to exclude a `date list` from a `datetime list`, the scenario is;

```
//LATES APPROVED LIST
 var lateReq = (from mk in db.Late
 where mk.EmpID == EmployeeRec.EmpId
 && mk.TeamLeadAppr == 1 && mk.DeptLeadAppr == 1
 select mk).ToList();

 List<DateTime> latesApproved = new List<DateTime>();
 List<LateRequest> lateRequest = new List<LateRequest>();

 foreach (var gk in lateReq)
 {
 latesApproved.Add(gk.lateDate.Value);
 }


//here lets say there is a date in latesApproved i.e. 13/3/2018 12:00:00 AM


//now in the `lateComings` list there are datetimes i.e. 13/3/2018 10:26:35 AM
 //exclude the lates approved list from the lateComings list
 List<DateTime> LateComingList = lateComings.ToList();
```

//excluding the above list does not exclude it as it cannot find the specified datetime in the `lateComings`

```
 List<DateTime> lateComingsWithoutApproved = LateComingList.Except(latesApproved).ToList();

 lateComings = lateComingsWithoutApproved;
```

//I need the final list with datetime both as I have further works with the time part of the list like below;

```
 //list of time differences 
 var timeDiff = new List<TimeSpan>();

 foreach (DateTime ts in lateComings)
 {

 if (ts.TimeOfDay > AT)//TimeSpan.FromHours(AT)
 {
 timeDiff.Add(ts.TimeOfDay - AT);//TimeSpan.FromHours(AT));
 }
 }

 countLates = lateComings.Count();
 //fetching the minutes from the above list which is in the format of 02:43:00


 var minutesList = timeDiff.Select(t => Convert.ToInt32(t.TotalMinutes)).ToList();
```

For a crystal picture;

`latesApproved list`

01/03/2018 12:00:00:AM

05/03/2018 12:00:00:AM

09/03/2018 12:00:00:AM

13/03/2018 12:00:00:AM

`lateComings list`

05/03/2018 11:00:32:AM

06/03/2018 10:54:33:AM

07/03/2018 08:34:47:AM

08/03/2018 12:30:40:AM

09/03/2018 10:03:00:AM

10/03/2018 11:03:00:AM

11/03/2018 11:30:40:AM

12/03/2018 10:30:40:AM

13/03/2018 08:30:00:AM

some final list should be like:

06/03/2018 10:54:33:AM

07/03/2018 08:34:47:AM

08/03/2018 12:30:40:AM

10/03/2018 11:03:00:AM

11/03/2018 11:30:40:AM

12/03/2018 10:30:40:AM

Comment: Are you just trying to find everyone from the late comings list that wasn't in the approved list?

Comment: It is not clear to me, what is your problem exactly. It looks like you have a solution to trim the time bits from your `DateTime`, which should solve the problem I think. Why is that not working? What is the problem still?

In the time bit processing do you really need to do those difference calculations? Can't you just say in your code use only the `Date` part of the `DateTime` field? It looks to me, you just trim down the hour parts anyway.

Comment: Indeed, I want all the datetime except the date in `latesApproved`

Comment: @CsabaBenko trimming the time part solves the problem but i dont want to trim it since i need it in the next part of code.

Comment: I added the code for something worked with your test data @Mickjohn

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trouble here is that when you run `Except`, it is looking at the actual date time value and considering the time so it won't match anything else. You'll need to use the overload which takes an equality comparer to ensure they are treated the same at the date level. Consider the following:

```
// class Program : IEqualityComparer<DateTime> // place something like this at the class definition.
bool IEqualityComparer<DateTime>.Equals(DateTime x, DateTime y)
{
    return x.Date == y.Date; // Compare the dates and not the times.
}

int IEqualityComparer<DateTime>.GetHashcode(DateTime obj)
{
    return obj.Date.GetHashCode();
}
```

In my example I used the class that I was writing this code in as the comparer. Being a console app it was the Program class so my call was as follows

```
var lateComingsWithoutApproved = LateComingList.Except(latesApproved, new Program()).ToList();
```

You'll need to substitute that for an instance of the class you use.

**Update**
In order for this to work, one of your classes (typically the one that needs to do the comparison) you have to implement the interface. Assuming your class is called LateArrivalController this is how you change the definition...

```
public class LateArrivalController : Controller, IEqualityComparer<DateTime>
```

You then pass it this way...

```
var lateComingsWithoutApproved = LateComingList.Except(latesApproved, this).ToList();
```

Comment: `'StatsController.IEqualityComparer<DateTime>.Equals(DateTime, DateTime)': containing type does not implement interface 'IEqualityComparer<DateTime>'`

Comment: `Error CS0540 'StatsController.GetHashcode(DateTime)': containing type does not implement interface 'IEqualityComparer<DateTime>'`

Comment: `Error CS0539 'StatsController.GetHashcode(DateTime)' in explicit interface declaration is not a member of interface`

Comment: I was editing my answer as you were posting this to include instructions on this. Give it a look.

Comment: I am using asp.net mvc

Comment: place the `: IEqualityComparer<DateTime>` after the class definition for the class you're working in, or you can create a small class just to do that. If you are using a controller, you can just put `this` in the method call.

Answer (score 1):

This looks like doing the job for me:

```
        List<DateTime> latesApproved = new List<DateTime>
        {
            Convert.ToDateTime("01/03/2018 12:00:00"),
            Convert.ToDateTime("05/03/2018 12:00:00"),
            Convert.ToDateTime("09/03/2018 12:00:00"),
            Convert.ToDateTime("13/03/2018 12:00:00")
        };

        List<DateTime> lateComings = new List<DateTime>
        {
            Convert.ToDateTime("05/03/2018 11:00:32"),
            Convert.ToDateTime("06/03/2018 10:54:33"),
            Convert.ToDateTime("07/03/2018 08:34:47"),
            Convert.ToDateTime("08/03/2018 12:30:40"),
            Convert.ToDateTime("09/03/2018 10:03:00"),
            Convert.ToDateTime("10/03/2018 11:03:00"),
            Convert.ToDateTime("11/03/2018 11:30:40"),
            Convert.ToDateTime("12/03/2018 10:30:40"),
            Convert.ToDateTime("13/03/2018 08:30:00")
        };

        List<DateTime> dateTimes = lateComings
            .Where(x => !latesApproved
                .Select(a => a.Date)
                .Contains(x.Date))
            .ToList();
```